# How to get AngularJS link to look/act like a Button?

Tags: html, angularjs, button

I have the following code in my AngularJS template:

```
<button class="submit-button" ng-click="myCtrl.doSomething1()">
    Do Something 1
</button>
<a class="submit-button" ui-sref="mystate({param1: 'a', param2: 'b'})">Do Something 2</a>
```

Here is the style:

```
.submit-button {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is how it gets rendered:

[image]

I would like `Do Something 2` to also appear and act as a button, just like `Do Something1`. But when clicked, it should send the user to the state specified in the `ui-sref`. How can I do it?

Comment: add class="submit-button" to a element as well

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just implement it like Do Something 1?

Comment: One is an angular state and another makes a call to an angular function. So I can't implement them the same way. adding the class "submit-button" doesn't make the link a button.

Comment: Just use button, your users will be glad:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZGqnp06DnI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose in button tag

```
 <a ui-sref="mystate({param1: 'a', param2: 'b'})"><button class="submit-button">test</button></a>
```

As Steve has mentioned, it is not valid html, but will work in most browser(for now)

You should be able to just apply the directive to a button element and it should work

```
   <button class="submit-button" ui-sref="mystate({param1: 'a', param2: 'b'})">test</button>
```

[Example using button as outer div and anchor tag as outer div](https://jsfiddle.net/hxuqnqsd/2/)

Comment: I suggested an edit that fixed a typo and re-arranged the ordering.
The `<a>` should be outside of the `<button>`, otherwise you can press on a part of the button where there is no text and nothing happens.

Comment: changed answer to match your findings

Comment: Nesting a `<button>` inside a link is not valid HTML. [there must be no interactive content or a element descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element)